# gmap store locator shows NoApiKeys found

Tags: magento-1.9, google-api, locations

I already have a magento and drupal website having gmap store locator and was working fine but from last two day, it is showing error. If i will generate a new api key does it will effect the existing module

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys ??

any guess ???

Answer (score 0):

Create Gmap api key from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Changing API Key **shouldn't affect existing module**.

Comment: But here i am not able to get where should i change the api key

Comment: Enable template path hints from System >> Configurations >> Developer and see from which phtml page the map is being called